# oplog operation in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Does oplog play a role in replication ,recovery or both.
If we are looking to only recover certain 'non-temporal' collections in our database - in case of a node recover - is it possible to do so selectively.
ie For a particular collection or data operation on a collection,is it possible to flag to omit the operation/collection from oplog.